# OAuth2 - Is it safe to return the access-token to the user?

Tags: .net, oauth

I'm new to OAuth (1 & 2), and I'm developing the server side of a mobile app that has a form with a "Fill Details from Google account" button. I don't need any long-range authentication\authorization.

From [here](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios) (Listing 2) I understand that the server should have a controller that:

- When called without a `code` in the query it will refer the user to get one (in an AuthorizationEndpoint such as: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth).
- When called with a `code` in the query, the **server** will send an HTTP request to the TokenEndpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token) to convert the code to an access-token (using a secret-key that is passed in the request).

At this stage, my server is suppose to be able to use the access-token to fetch the user's details from https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me - and then return the details to the user's app, to fill in its form.

Am I (the server developer) allowed to be lazy and return the access-token to the user, instead of its details? i.e., let the user app make the request to https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me.

This will allow, in the future, to give more power to the client app without changing the code on my server.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplication? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22767/is-it-safe-to-store-twitter-access-tokens-client-side
I am not really sure...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are speaking of the [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) which return directly an access token to the client. You have better time to directly look at the RFC.

My thought is it is safe if you use https. If you use [JWT](http://openid.net/specs/draft-jones-json-web-token-07.html#anchor1) (json web token), the access_token can be signed (JSON Web Signature (JWS)) and encrypted (JSON Web Encryption (JWE)) in the payload.